# UWP Drag and Drop remove glyph and caption

Tags: uwp, drag-and-drop

In my UWP app I drag a list item from one list and drop it on another list. While dragging I see a red circle glyph and/or "move" or "copy" text . I don't want this because I am not moving or copying anything and I don't wat to show the red circle glyph either because it indicates that you cannot drag the item but you can. I can get rid of the glyph and caption with the following code:

```
    private void ListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = false;
        e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
    }
```

But I have to implement this code for each control I drag the list item over.

Is there any way to never show the glyph and caption while dragging an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can't disable this behaviour on the dragitem itself, however you can disable this behaviour by making your containing element (Grid or whatever you element is containing the controls on your view) a drop target and implement the DragOver event like so:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" DragOver="HideDragInfo" AllowDrop="True">
```

then implement the HideDragInfo like this:

```
private void HideDragInfo(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = false;
    e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = false;
}
```